# Django "dynamic" verification form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a verification form in Django that presents a user with a list of choices, only one of which is valid.

For example, for a user whose favourite pizza toppings includes pineapple and roquefort—

> What is your favourite pizza topping?
>
> - Ham
> - Pineapple
> - Anchovie

**The choices should be random every time, in both order and values, but always have one valid answer.** For example, if the user refreshes the page, the form might be—

> What is your favourite pizza topping?
>
> - Mozarella
> - Ham
> - Roquefort

How do I build such a form? I'm swamped. We have to record somewhere what the valid choice is for a specific form:

- Create entries in the database for each question (not scalable)?
- Set it in the session (hacky)?
- Based on user ID (could be predictible)?

**Edit**—We do store the list of pizza toppings in the database—

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    favourite_pizza_toppings = ManyToManyField(PizzaTopping)
```

What I want is a form such as—

```
class QuestionForm(Form):
    questions = ChoiceField(choices=(('a', RANDOMLY_CHOSEN_OPTION_A),
                                     ('b', RANDOMLY_CHOSEN_OPTION_B),
                                     ('c', RANDOMLY_CHOSEN_OPTION_C)))
```

Where, each time it's instantiated, all `RANDOMLY_CHOSEN_OPTION` are chosen randomly from `PizzaTopping.objects.all`, with only one being a `PizzaTopping` also in `UserProfile.favourite_pizza_toppings`.

We'll need to verify the form when the user POSTs it though—and that's the tricky bit. We have to somehow record which is the valid choice (`a`, `b`, or `c`) for each instantiated form. How can we do this?

Comment: Do you have any code for now?

Comment: it seems you need to know a users 'valid' choice.  So there needs to be a mapping of choice/question to user.

Comment: @dm03514—I already have the "valid" choices in the DB. I'll update the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to build up the choices in the the form **init** method, otherwise the form elements choices will be the same each time the page loads (they won't change).

```
class QuestionForm(Form):
    questions = ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['questions'].choices = set_up_choices() # function that creates list

    clean_questions(self):
        # do your validation of the question selection
        # here you could check whether the option selected matches
        # a correct value, if not throw a form validation exception
        return self.cleaned['questions']
```

Comment: Very handy. Simply ended up populating the choices with random values (but one valid), and then in the clean function, check the set value against the users fields. Simples